# $\phi(a) = 0 \implies \phi(b^*ab) = 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\phi: A \to \mathbb{C}$ be a state on a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$ and let $a \in A$ be a positive element with $\phi(a) = 0$. Is it true that $\phi(b^*ab)=0$ for every $b \in B?$

Some observations:

- Since the unitaries of $A$ span $A$, it suffices to check the claim for $b$ a unitary.
- We can try to apply results about completely positive maps/multiplicative maps/Cauchy-Schwarz  inequality.
- If $a=1$ and $\phi(a)=0$, then $\phi = 0$ so the statement is trivial.
- An example: Let $\phi: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{C}: A \mapsto Tr(A)$. If $\phi(A) = 0$. Then (since we  may assume that $B$ is a unitary) $\phi(B^*AB) = \phi(A)=0$ so for this functional the claim follows.
- By more or less the same argument, the claim also holds if $A$ is an abelian $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: Could you check such property on some examples ?

Comment: @InfiniteLooper I made some edits. Do you know the answer to the question?

Comment: Do you know other states on say matrices ?

Comment: @InfiniteLooper Sure $A \mapsto \langle A\xi, \xi\rangle$ where $\xi$ is a unit vector on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: So for this state, we should show that $\langle A\xi, \xi\rangle = 0 \implies \langle AB\xi, B\xi\rangle=0$ and I guess this will be false in general?

Comment: I was thinking of this, yes :) Maybe you can then post your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fails easily. Take $A=\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{C}^2)\cong M_2$ and let $\xi=(1,0)\in\mathbb{C}^2$. Then $\xi$ is a unit vector, so $\phi(x):=\langle x\xi,\xi\rangle$ defines a state on $A$. Note that if $p$ is the orthogonal projection onto the 1 dimensional subspace spanned by $\xi$, then $\phi(p^\bot)=0$. But $p^\bot$ is precisely the projection onto the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $\xi'=(0,1)$. It is well known that, projections of the same rank are unitarily equivalent in Hilbert spaces, so there exists a unitary $u\in\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{C}^2)$ such that $p=u^*p^\bot u$. (if you don't believe me, try the unitary $u=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$).

If your claim was true, since $\phi(p^\bot)=0$, we would also have $\phi(u^*p^\bot u)=0$, i.e. $\phi(p)=0$. But $\phi(p)=1$.